# Search for substring in an item of List

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have list :

```
List<string> str = new List<string>();  
str.Add("asdf---US,IN");  
str.Add("asdg---UK,IN");  
str.Add("asjk---RU,IN");  
str.Add("asrt---IT,DE");
```

I want to get List  like ("asdf","asdg","asjk") when i enter "IN". For this i'm doing :

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = 
        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("asr", 
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
List<string> str = new List<string>();  
str.Add("asdf---US,IN");  
str.Add("asdg---UK,IN");  
str.Add("asjk---RU,IN");  
str.Add("asrt---IT,DE"); 
var getArray = str.Where<string>(item => regEx.IsMatch(item)).ToList<string>();
str = getArray.ToList();
```

str is having correct result. but it is containing whole item like "asdf---US,IN","asdg---UK,IN", "asjk---RU,IN". I only want first four character in item in list i.e., 'asdf", "asdg", "asjk". What condition can i put in lambda expression, to get list i want?

Comment: Then you need to get the matches, not just test that it had 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its only going to be first four characters use [string.SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var getArray = str.Where(item => regEx.IsMatch(item))
                  .Select(r=> r.Substring(0,4))
                  .ToList();
```

You also doesn't need to specify `<string>` cast with `where` and `ToList`. Items in your list are already of type string.

EDIT:

If you are only looking for those strings that ends with "IN" you may get rid of the regex and use [string.EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx):

```
var getArray = str.Where(item => item.EndsWith("IN"))
                  .Select(r=> r.Substring(0,4))
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be

```
.*?(?=---.*?IN)
```

and the query should be

```
var getArray = str.Where<string>(item => regEx.IsMatch(item)).Select<string>(item => regEx.Match(item)).ToList<string>();
```